# $http.get keeps launching new queries

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm encountering a weird issue in my AngularJS app. It's supposed to access a number of values from a cookie 'login', pass those values to an API endpoint and then return the API response.
This works fine, except it keeps launching new GET queries continuously every 500ms. This results in an unending stream of the console error: "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" and forcing me to kill it manually.

Where is this weird behavior coming from, and how can I limit it to just 1 run?

**workbooks.html**

```
<body>
<div>This is the workbooks view.</div>
<span>{{callQueryWorkbooksForUser()}}</span>
<section ui-view>{{response}}</section>
</body>
```

**workbooks.controller.js**

```
'use strict';
(function() {

  class WorkbooksComponent {
    constructor($scope, $http, $cookies) {
      $scope.callQueryWorkbooksForUser = function() {
        var login = JSON.parse($cookies.get('login'))
        var auth_token = login.authentication_token;
        var siteid = login.site_id;
        var userid = login.user_id;

        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/api/sites/' + siteid + '/users/' + userid + '/workbooks',
          params: {
            auth_token: auth_token
          }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          $scope.response = response.data
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          $scope.response = 'Server error'
        });

      };

    }
  }

  angular.module('orbitApp')
    .component('workbooks', {
      templateUrl: 'app/workbooks/workbooks.html',
      controller: WorkbooksComponent
    });

})();
```

Comment: {{callQueryWorkbooksForUser}} will be executed in every digest cycle. You shouldnt make any http call and do any intensive work in a function that can be called every digest cycle.

Comment: How would you suggest I specify it?

Comment: I have added an answer. You will have to do this in $onInit of the controller. Verify this by adding to your code, as I am not familiar with class notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the http request in init block of your controller.

```
  class WorkbooksComponent {
    constructor($scope, $http, $cookies) {

        this.$onInit = function() {
            var login = JSON.parse($cookies.get('login'))
            var auth_token = login.authentication_token;
            var siteid = login.site_id;
            var userid = login.user_id;

            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/api/sites/' + siteid + '/users/' + userid + '/workbooks',
              params: {
                auth_token: auth_token
              }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              $scope.response = response.data
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              $scope.response = 'Server error'
            });
        };

    }
  }
```

Comment: That seems to limit it to just 1 GET request (thank you!), however the returned {{response}} stays blank.

Comment: Never mind, behavior of {{response}} seems to have been a glitch unrelated to this solution, solved it!